# Как функции узнают, какую специализацию шаблона использовать?

Tags: rust

В данном выражении, как компилятор выводит, какую специализацию шаблона `parse()` использовать?

```
let guess: u8 = "-42".parse().expect("Not a number!");
```

Откуда он узнаёт, что нужно использовать именно вариант `parse()` для `u8`, а не для `f64` например? Какова логика разбора этого выражения компилятором?

---

<sub>Контекста ради: я пока на стадии чтения третьей главы букваря, а такие выражения на фоне опыта в Си и плюсах кажутся магией.</sub>

---

**[Added]**
Истинная магия с выводом типов начинается, когда они выводятся в абсолютно другом операторе:

```
let mut vec = Vec::new();
let val = "-42".parse().expect("Not a number!");
// ...
vec.push(3u8); // благодаря этому вектор типизируется как Vec<u8>
vec.push(val); // т.к. типизацию вектора известна выводится тип `val` и `parse()`
```

Comment: "такие выражения на фоне опыта в Си и плюсах кажутся магией" - почему это? Вроде как основной мутный момент здесь - это переход с разбора слева направо в разбор в обратном направлении, но для С/C++ спиральность - это норма.

Comment: @VTT, «магия» в том, что в плюсах выводы однонаправлены: подвыражение никогда не знает и не учитывает, какой результат оно должно вернуть: он может быть выведен только на основе того, что внутри выражения… и у меня есть подозрения, что вся эта система справится и с выводом куда большего количества параметров из разных шаблонов, так что хотелось бы понять границы её возможностей и как оно работает… В принципе уже начал понимать, что для вывода строится какая-то система предикатов и производится вывод (что-то вроде того, как в прологе), но пока не могу всё это облечь в ответ…

Comment: @VTT, кстати, забыл спросить: wth «спиральность»?

Comment: Это я подразумевал [спиральное правило чтения объявлений](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Straight-Declarations/blob/master/Meme.png). Шаблоны в С++ добавили после перегрузок, так что возможности выводить что-то из результата не было, как не было возможности перегружать по возвращаемому значению. Второй пример это скорее уже трешачок навроде [comefrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM).